# Warning: (1265L, u"Data truncated for column 'test_end_date' at row 1")

Tags: python, mysql, sql

When I execute INSERT query in Python, I get the following warning `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:68: Warning: (1265L, u"Data truncated for column 'test_end_date' at row 1")`.

When I open phpMyAdmin and check the inserted record, I see that `test_end_date` is inserted as `0000-00-00`, while other dates are inserted correctly, e.g. `2018-01-24`, etc. Why??

```
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `logo_path` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
   UNIQUE KEY (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO `projects` (`title`, `logo_path`, `description`, `test_start_date`, `test_end_date`, `start_date`, `end_date`) VALUES ('title','http://....png', 'This is the test','2018-01-28', '2018-02-30', '2018-03-10', '2018-03-28')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
2018-02-30
```

is not a valid date since febuary has 29 days max.

Comment: Is it possible to not insert the whole row in the table if this warning appears?

Comment: @Markus Wouldn't it be better to fix your code and not try to insert invalid dates?